# Slow view rendering when using Blade components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have been hitting this strange performance issue with Laravel Blade when using components. I usually have between 10 - 200 components on each view. I see the same issue in production as well as on my local machine, on all of my apps running both Laravel 7 and 8.

Each component slows down the rendering of the view. Rendering a simple view with 100 empty components takes around **0.2s**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>

    @foreach (range(0, 100) as $i)
      <x-test />  <!-- empty component -->
    @endforeach

</body>
```

Rendering it without any components takes around **0.005s** I have tried:

- Caching my views - no effect
- Using different Blade syntax `@include('components.test')` - no effect
- Creating components via `artisan` command - no effect
- Different environments and Laravel versions - no effect

Not using Blade components and writing out contents of the component straight into the view improves performance, but that would mean repeating myself quite often.

Any ideas what may cause this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any opcaching?

Comment: Yes, OPcache is enabled. Using PHP 7.4 with nginx 1.14.0